# Fetching data from website error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub GetDataFromLandings()
    Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:F250") = Null

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 2 To lastrow
            RequeryLandings .Cells(x, "G")
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RequeryLandings(address As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NewRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/" & address, _
        Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=22NA"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

            DoEvents
```

Above code gets data from website https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/

and loops through different values taken from column G :

```
RequeryLandings .Cells(x, "G")
```

so URL address is in this form

```
"URL;https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/" & address,
```

where   & address    is the values from column G.

If the first row in G column is *SP-LRC* then it searches URL

```
"URL;https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/SP-LRC"
```

I am trying to get data from different website which is

http://www.airliners.net/search?registrationActual=SP-LRC&display=detail

and I can not figure out how the code should change to properly work for that address...in this case `SP-LRC` is not in the end of address but is before `&display=detail`

Comment: Next time could you please format your code. Will save us a lot of time either trying to format it or read code which is not intdented properly.

Comment: I see my mistake now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `string`

```
http://www.airliners.net/search?registrationActual=SP-LRC&display=detail
```

can be written as

```
"http://www.airliners.net/search?registrationActual=" & "SP-LRC" & "&display=detail"
```

So change

```
"URL;https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/" & address
```

to

```
"URL;http://www.airliners.net/search?registrationActual=" & address & "&display=detail"
```